# How to typecast void* to Point Cloud pointer

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

In the Point Cloud Library, a pointer to a cloud is created like so:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloudPTR(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)
```

I need to typecast void* to a cloud pointer. What would be the syntax for this?

More specifically, I am trying to use the `shmat()` function and write a point cloud to shared memory, hence the need to cast to cloud pointer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This depends on what `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr` resolves to (i.e. is it a shared_ptr? a scalar pointer?)

Comment: Another thing to note: you can only put something into shared memory if it's a POD type (as defined in the C++ spec). This is a relatively narrow definition.

Comment: The syntax is `static_cast<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr>(yourptr);`  , however it is very unlikely to work if you put this in shared memory  (even in shared memory, different processors have different address spaces)

Comment: @iAdjunct, yes it's a shared pointer.

Comment: @M.M,  Thanks, will try that syntax and let you know.

Comment: You can't cast this to a `shared_ptr` - you'll have to either reference it (with a dummy destructor in a `shared_ptr`) or copy it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the sender's side:

```
void * pSharedMemory = ... ; // from wherever
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr ptr = ... ; // from wherever
memcpy ( pSharedMemory , static_cast<void const*>(ptr.get()) , sizeof(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>) ) ;
```

On the receiver's side:

```
template <typename T> nothing ( T* ) { }

void * pSharedMemory = ... ; // from wherever
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr ptr ( static_cast<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*>(pSharedMemory) , &nothing<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > ) ; // sets the destructor to do nothing
```

This method references the memory with a `shared_ptr` but doesn't do any management on it. This is more of a compatibility layer.

Another way, on the receiver's side:

```
void * pSharedMemory = ... ; // from wherever
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> * pThing = static_cast<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > ( pSharedMemory ) ;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr ptr = std::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > ( *pThing ) ; // copies it
```

A note on safety:

Because this is dependent upon `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` being a POD type. You can make sure this assumption is valid by putting this in your file somewhere:

```
static_assert ( std::is_pod<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >::value ) ;
```

Or, if you're not using C++11:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT (( boost::is_pod<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > )) ;
```

This will, at compile time, make sure the object is a POD type; if it's not, you cannot use it with shared memory.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, what the shared pointer is not POD so I had to abandon this approach. Also, for the static_assert, there has to be be a second argument containing a string.

Comment: Ahh. Haven't actually used static_assert yet - but make heavy use of BOOST_MPL_ASSERT. Didn't realize they added that, which is a good idea.

Comment: Note that there was an edit suggested to change `std::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > ( *pThing ) ;` to simply construct the pointer with `(pThing)`. This is a very bad solution because that gives ownership of the shared memory to the pointer, which will call `delete` at the end. There are workarounds to this, but may not be what you want. If you have troubles with this code working, it may be because your class doesn't have a copy constructor available.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I need to typecast void* to a cloud pointer.

In some code I did some time ago, g++ v2.5.1 compiler accepts the following ...

```
 void* v_shm_data = < ret val from your  ::shmat() >
 //  shared memory attach to this process--^^^^^^^
 //  the os selects the memory address, and returns the void*

 assert(reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1) != v_shm_data);  // abort on error

 shm_data = static_cast<Shm_process_data*>(v_shm_data);
 //   my data type ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^ --- void*
```

My coding environment has changed, so I have some work to do to confirm this still works ... sorry.

Note - the shm_data is POD only ... no containers or stl, no virtual methods, no pointers (maybe offset descriptors).